# How to validate if any new changes in Page using Selenium java - UI changes

Tags: java, selenium, user-interface

I have been asked to validate the UI changes in the product(on all pages). If there are any new changes/features introduced or if there are any UI issues to be captured in automation ( Selenium, JAVA). What would be the best approach to achieve this result?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar task, and my solution was the following:

I created a folder where I saved the body html of the page into text files.
Then the logic was to run a test where it creates current text files with the body html. Finally comparing these 2 files and seeing if there is any difference.

I have used the RestAssured API library to achieve this goal. So it is a mix of using API responses logic and comparing 2 files. You might have to replace some dynamic Strings in between.

The code looks similar to this:

```
@Test --> here you can use a data provider 
public void verifyHTMLConsistency(String URL) throws Exception {

Path pathCurrent;
Path pathBaseline;

URL = "url-of-the-page";

// get the bodyHTML text, by giving the URL input.
String bodyHTMLText = given()
                .when()
                .get(URL)
                .then()
                .log()
                .body().extract().asString();

bodyHTMLText = returnAllResultsBetweenValues(bodyHTMLText);


        // 2
        pathCurrent = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/reportFolder/CurrentTestTextFiles/" + reportName + ".txt");
        writeFile(pathCurrent, bodyHTMLText);
        pathBaseline = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/reportFolder/BaseLineTextFiles/" + reportName + ".txt");


        // 3 open the text files in BufferedReader
        BufferedReader readCurrentFile    = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(String.valueOf(pathCurrent)));
        BufferedReader readerBaselineFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(String.valueOf(pathBaseline)));

        assertTrue(sameContentWithFileReader(readCurrentFile, readerBaselineFile,reportName));
}

static void writeFile(Path path, String content) throws IOException {

        Files.write(path, content.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
}

private static boolean sameContentWithFileReader(BufferedReader reader1, BufferedReader reader2, String reportName) throws IOException {

        String line1 = reader1.readLine();
        String line2 = reader2.readLine();

        boolean flag = true;
        int lineNum  = 1;

        while (line1 != null || line2 != null)
        {
            if(line1 == null || line2 == null)
            {
                flag = false;

                break;
            }
            else if(! line1.equalsIgnoreCase(line2))
            {
                flag = false;

                break;
            }

            line1 = reader1.readLine();
            line2 = reader2.readLine();

            lineNum++;
        }

        if(flag)
        {
            System.out.println("Two files have same content.");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Two files have different content. They differ at line "+lineNum);
            System.out.println("-------------------");
            System.out.println("CURRENTFILE has "+line1+" || at line "+lineNum);
            System.out.println("-------------------");
            System.out.println("BASELINE has "+line2+" || at line "+lineNum);
        }

        reader1.close();
        reader2.close();

        return flag;
}

// to replace some dynamic values
private static String returnAllResultsBetweenValues(String bodyHTMLText){

        String[] stringToBeReplacedBottomMultiple;

        try{

            stringToBeReplacedBottomMultiple = 
            StringUtils.substringsBetween(bodyHTMLText,
                    "Text1",
                    "Text2");

            // replace this string with a test text
            for(String results : stringToBeReplacedBottomMultiple){
                bodyHTMLText = bodyHTMLText.replace(results, "---QA---");

            }

        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        return bodyHTMLText;
}
```

Hope this helps.